# Who was the orc who wanted to leave Mordor and have his own band of brigands?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings

In *The Lord of the Rings* there was a conversation between two orcs, where one of them expressed the desire to leave Mordor and return to a life of small scale brigandry.

Who was this orc, and in which book did this conversation occur?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a passage in Lord of the Rings told from the perspective of an orc?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/190501/is-there-a-passage-in-lord-of-the-rings-told-from-the-perspective-of-an-orc). It's Gorbag.

Comment: The answer is the same, but the two questions seem distinct -- one about a particular event that happened in the book, one about narrative perspectives.

Comment: Anyone finding this question will **instantly** find the answer on the other question. Not only is it the top answer but it's also accepted. That's usually good enough for us.

Comment: Yeah, being a duplicate isn't necessarily a negative thing, especially in this case where the questions are different, but have the same answer. Both are good questions and each serves as a pointer to a single good answer.

Comment: Got it, thanks for the clue!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's Gorbag's suggestion to Shagrat at the high pass above Minas Morgul. They have just taken the unconscious Frodo prisoner and Sam hears them though he and they are in different tunnels.

> "...But anyway, if it does go well, there should be a lot more room. What d'you say? - if we get a chance, you and me'll slip off and set up somewhere on our own with a few trusty lads, somewhere where there's good loot nice and handy, and no big bosses.'
>
> 'Ah! ' said Shagrat. 'Like old times.'
> <sub>*The Two Towers, book IV, chapter 10 - The Choices of Master Samwise.*</sub>